# jQuery $.get() not working and calling express get

Tags: jquery, html, express, mongoose

I'm implementing a feature on a site run on a local server where it checks actively whether a username is available or not. The problem is that $.get() seems to not work at all and isn't calling the corresponding app.get() function.

script.js:

```
 $('#username').keyup(function() {
    var username = $('#username').val();


    $.get('/getCheckUsername', {username: username}, function(result) {
        alert('Query done.') //just to test that it has been called
        alert(result);
    })

})
```

No alerts are showing up on any keystroke on the page.

routes.js:

```
app.get('/getCheckUsername', signupController.getCheckUsername);
```

signUpController:

```
getCheckUsername: function(req, res) {
    var username = req.query.username;

    database.findOne(User, {username: username}, 'username', function(result) {
        res.send(result);
    });

}
```

Comment: Check the console in dev tools for any errors. Also check the network tab after making the request to see the state of the response

Comment: Does the `#username` element exist?  Is the `keyup` event successfully being bound and handled?  When you debug in the browser's debugging tools, what specifically happens?

Comment: The keyup is working fine. I tested it by putting an alert call at the start of the function before.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The console says that `"script.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function"`

Comment: Did you try with `$.get("http://localhost:port/getCheckUsername")`?

Comment: @SS-Salt: Then `$.get` is not a function.  Where are you loading jQuery?  What version are you using?

Comment: @SS-Salt in that case either `$` does not refer to jQuery, or you're using the 'slim' branch of jQuery and need to change that to the full version

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That seems to be the solution. Thank you. Didn't realize that the slim version had no Ajax.